# Getting status code 997 when create the user in owncloud

Tags: cloud, owncloud, cloud-storage

I am trying to create the user through owncloud User Provisioning API, when trying to request the below api:

> curl -X POST
>   http://admin:secret@localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users -d
>   userid="user1" -d password="user1"

I get the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ocs>
 <meta>
  <status>failure</status>
  <statuscode>997</statuscode>
  <message>Unauthorised</message>
 </meta>
 <data/>
</ocs>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `admin:secret` username/pass combination? That's the same error you get when the admin's password is incorrect. Also, make sure you're pointing to the right http/https endpoint as these might yield different results. You can test against `https://admin:admin@demo.owncloud.com` to see this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That issue was causing due to the `secret` contained the combination of special character like `@`. Bellow is sample link

https://admin:secret@demo.owncloud.com

look like

https://admin:abc@12@demo.owncloud.com, where `abc@12` is a secret/password.

Due to two `@` symbol in secret, it was taking the domain from the `@12` instead of `@demo`.